# Should question be marked as duplicates when the "duplicate" was closed as too broad?

Tags: discussion, duplicate

The question [How can I create a file with multiple lines from the command-line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35550/how-can-i-create-a-file-with-multiple-lines-from-the-command-line?noredirect=1#comment421559_35550) (for short A) was closed as a duplicate of [How to create a simple .txt (text) file using terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159672/how-to-create-a-simple-txt-text-file-using-terminal)(B).

But B was closed as being too broad. Now the new question A which is to the point is closed as a duplicated?

Does this make sense? I would have guessed that when a question is too broad one would need to create a question that is more precise or split it into smaller questions.

Could someone explain to me where my interpretation is wrong?

Comment: B is broad, A is slightly less broad. That does not make A "to the point".

Comment: @muru ok one could ask the question for one specific command (cat, echo, printf, ...). Would this then also be a duplicate of B?

Comment: Then you'd have the questions: a) Why that specific command? and b) What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @muru Ok so the question is not for Unix&Linux in general.